# Efficient bit shuffling between multiple words

Tags: c, assembly, arm, bit-manipulation, shuffle

Say I have 8 32-bit registers:

```
A 0-31        E 0-31
B 0-31        F 0-31
C 0-31        G 0-31
D 0-31        H 0-31
```

And I want their bits rearranged like:

```
A' := A0 E0 A8 E8 A16 E16 A24 E24 B0 F0 B8 F8 B16 F16 B24 F24 C0 G0 ...etc. H24
B' := A1 E1 A9 E9 A17 E17 A25 E25 B1 F1 B9 F9 B17 F17 B25 F25 C1 G1 ...etc. H25 
C' := A2 E2 A10 E10 A18 E18 A26 E26 B2 ... etc.
D' := ... etc.
E' := ... etc.
F' := ... etc.
G' := ... etc.
H' := ... etc.
```

What would be the most efficient way to compute this shuffling in either C or ARM assembly? (So no intel with SSE, no 64-bit registers, not enough registers to contain both input and output.) The calculator at http://programming.sirrida.de/calcperm.php is really nice, but it doesn't easily extend to multiple words. I believe it can be done more efficiently than the naive way of selecting one bit at the time.

Comment: What CPU architecture ?

Comment: There is no efficient way to do it. You might think of *elegant* way of doing it, but it's about algorithms.

Comment: If you posted code for the "naive way of selecting one bit at the time" then 1) Answerers would have a clear idea of your goal.  2) Answers could rate their results against your baseline.  Since this basic step was not done, looks like this post is obliging SO to do a fair amount of work for this answer.

Comment: The benefit of assember language would be that you can leverage the carry flag to avoid some bit-copying.

Comment: Thinking about it, you have 32*8=256 bits to translate. That should be possible with 256 shifts + 256 rotates, or 512 rotates, in assembler. If you can hold all input+output bits in registers all the time.

Comment: On x86 with BMI2, look into `pdep` / `pext`.  That might help with Harold's suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. I'm using ARM. So no 64-bit registers, practically free rotates/shifts when combined with some other instructions, and not enough registers to contain both input and output.

Comment: So is Neon SIMD allowed for this, or are you working with a low-end ARM CPU that lacks Neon ?

Comment: Cortex M4, so no Neon. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make components `A0 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ A8 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ A16` etc (just trivial masking).
And similar for the other registers, you can easily make this:

```
A0 E0 B0 F0 C0 G0 D0 H0 A8 E8 ..
```

Which you can turn into the right order with two bit_permute_step's, as given by calcperm:

```
x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x00cc00cc, 6);  // Bit index swap 1,3
x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x0000f0f0, 12);  // Bit index swap 2,4
```

Similar story for the other registers, just offset a bit.

Essentially moving 4 bits at once, with a bit of fixup which only happens 8 times.

Comment: Thanks. That would probably be very fast if I had 17 registers (8 input + 8 output + mask). Unfortunately I don't. Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: I have 14 32-bit registers available.

Answer (score 0):

```
; 1) Copy the top most 8 bits of H into the lowest bits of the output registers:

lsr H  ; H.31 -> carry
rol H' ; carry -> H'.0

lsr H  ; H.30 -> carry
rol G' ; carry -> G'.0

lsr H
rol F'

...

lsr H  ; H.24 -> carry
rol A' ; carry to A'.0

; 2) go on with top 8 bits of D

lsr D  ; D.31 -> carry
rol H' ; H'.0 -> H'.1 and carry -> H'.0

lsr D
rol G'

...

lsr D
rol A'
```

Continue until all bits are in place. The last step is

```
lsr A  ; A.0 -> carry
rol A' ; A'.0 -> A'.1 -> A'.2 ... and carry -> A'.0
```

Answer (score 0):

the fastest version I came up with:

```
// merges 32 bit a (low) and b (hi) into single 64 bit
#define m(a, b) (((uint64_t) (a)) | (((uint64_t) (b)) << 32))

// gets bit at position opos and moves it to position npos
#define s(a, opos, npos) (((opos) >= (npos)) ? (((a) & ( ((uint64_t)1) << (opos))) >> ((opos) - (npos))) : (((a) & (((uint64_t)1) << (opos))) << ((npos) - (opos))))

// gets 8 different bits from 64 bit number and puts them together into 1 byte, starting from idx
#define b(a, idx) (s(a, 0, idx) | s(a, 32, (idx - 1)) | s(a, 8, (idx - 2)) | s(a, 40, (idx - 3)) | s(a, 16, (idx - 4)) | s(a, 48, (idx - 5)) | s(a, 24, (idx - 6)) | s(a, 56, (idx - 7)))

// takes 8 32 bit registers in in, outputs in out
void shuffle(const uint32_t* in, uint32_t* out) {
    uint64_t t[4] = { m(in[0], in[4]), m(in[1], in[5]), m(in[2], in[6]), m(in[3], in[7]) };
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++, t[0] >>= 1, t[1] >>= 1, t[2] >>= 1, t[3] >>= 1)
        out[i] = b(t[0], 31) | b(t[1], 23) | b(t[2], 15) | b(t[3], 7);
}
```

the only "optimization" in comparison to straight forward approach is to merge two 32 bit registers into single 64 bit, so we can reduce number of shifts in loop

Comment: Yes, on an architecture with 64-bit registers where you can address and rotate the lower and upper half separately. I'm using ARM though. Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: @BlaBlaat yeah, for 32bit registers this approach will be slower, anyway will leave it here for future

Answer (score 0):

On x86 with SSE: `punpcklbw` ([`_mm_unpacklo_epi8`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3&expand=5577,4976,3115,903,1798,3017,5604&text=punpcklb) can interleave bytes of the source regs.

Use vector shifts then pmovmskb to grab the high bit of each byte, giving you results like
`A0 E0 A8 E8 A16 E16 A24 E24`

Then combine these byte results to get the 8 dest registers.  This kind of sucks, because it requires a shift/pmovmskb for each of result byte.  There are 8 * 4 result bytes, so that's a lot of code.

Comment: OPs question does say _"assuming no SSE instructions"_

Comment: oops.  I'll leave this answer here, in case anyone's interested in seeing what you might do with SSE.

Comment: You can probably do something similar with Neon SIMD, since OP has now belatedly informed us that he is working with an ARM CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party but I'll post an answer anyway.

Firstly, notice that the bytes in the output words each use only even/odd bits of a pair of input words. combining the odd bits of A with the even bits of B gives all the bits necessary for the first byte of A,C,E,G. Code for the resulting permutation can be found via the calculator linked above and simplifies to two bit swapping operations per word. The resulting bytes can be written back to memory in their correct locations and read back if necessary.

Permuting the bytes within a word costs about as much as writing out the bytes to memory but is also possible.

Cost is 17 bit operations per word. A little less on ARM where rotations are free. Vectorisation is easy with byte shuffling replacing the last step.

The following vanilla C code should do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int32_t inline bit_permute_step(int32_t x, int32_t m, int shift) {
    int32_t t;
    t = ((x >> shift) ^ x) & m;
    x = (x ^ t) ^ (t << shift);
    return x;
    }

void permute(int32_t input[8], int32_t output[8]){
    int8_t *outputc=(int8_t*)output;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        int32_t A=input[3-i];
        int32_t E=input[3-i+4];
        //swap the even bits of A/B/C/D with the odd bits of E/F/G/H
        int32_t t=(A^(E>>1))&0x55555555;
        A^=t;E^=t<<1;
        A = bit_permute_step(A, 0x00cc00cc, 6);  // Bit index swap 1,3
        E = bit_permute_step(E, 0x00cc00cc, 6);  // Bit index swap 1,3
        A = bit_permute_step(A, 0x0000f0f0, 12);  // Bit index swap 2,4
        E = bit_permute_step(E, 0x0000f0f0, 12);  // Bit index swap 2,4
        outputc[i+0 ]=A>>24;
        outputc[i+4 ]=E>>24;
        outputc[i+8 ]=A>>16;
        outputc[i+12]=E>>16;
        outputc[i+16]=A>>8;
        outputc[i+20]=E>>8;
        outputc[i+24]=A;
        outputc[i+28]=E;
        }
    }


void printBits(unsigned int num){
   for(int bit=31;bit>=0; bit--){
      printf("%i", (num>>bit)&1);
      if(bit && !(bit&7)){printf(" ");}
   }printf("\n");
}

int32_t main(){
    volatile int32_t input[8]=
{0xf<<0,0xf<<8,0xf<<16,0xf<<24,0xf<<4,0xf<<12,0xf<<20,0xf<<28};
    int32_t output[8]={-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
    printf("input\n");
    permute((int32_t*)input,output);
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        printf("  %c:",'A'+i);
        printBits(input[i]);
    }
    printf("output\n");
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        printf("  %c:",'A'+i);
        printBits(output[i]);
    }
    
}
```